# Excel countif or index/match formula

Tags: excel, indexing, match, countif

This involves two files. If B2 (file2) is somewhere in column A (file1) (and matches exactly), then go to D2 (file2) and check if that is anywhere in corresponding cell in column E (which wouldn't match exactly) and return yes or no.

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: Please take the time to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then come back and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55281477/edit) You already have an idea what you need. Show us what you've tried and explain to us how it fails to achieve the desired goal

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that all data appears in sheet 1 in both File 1 & File 2.You could try the below formula from another sheet. Have in mind that the for the not exact match i use i use "*" in the formula which means that will match anything starting with the value of D2. in other cases would not match.

**File 1**

[image]

**File 2**

[image]

**Another File**
[image]

```
=IF(AND(IFERROR(IF(MATCH('[File 2.xlsx]Sheet1'!B2,'[File 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!A:A,0)>0,"Match"),"No match")="Match",IFERROR(IF(MATCH('[File 2.xlsx]Sheet1'!D2&"*",'[File 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!E:E,0)>0,"Match"),"No match")="Match"),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.  This almost works perfectly.   The problem I'm having is that column D and E aren't going to be a perfect match.  For example,

in column D, you will have "Ireland", in column E, you will have  something like "United Arab EmiratesPhilippinesIreland Germany"

Comment: hm. that's not working. not sure what I can say to help you out?

I know the only problem with the 1st formula you gave was that the cells D and E needed to match exactly. otherwise it was perfect

Comment: @rishi could you please try another time.

Comment: still no, I also tried changing it to "*D2*" but didn't work....

tried going through evaluate formula and when it reaches E:E, it's showing that portion as #N/A

Comment: hey mate...I change D2&"*" to "*"&D2&"*" and at first glance, looks like it's working.....will get back to you if not - thanks so much for the help

Comment: eh, not quite.  not sure how it's returning "yes" when column D has "France" and column E has "Hong Kong
India
Malaysia
Indonesia
Pakistan
Philippines
South Korea
Turkey
U.K."